# MySQL Select return as JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I read about the MySQL 5.7 features and I'm curious is it possible the return the given rows of the select in JSON format or return the whole result as JSON format. 
My data is looks like a normal MySQL table:

```
| 13162 |         1 |  178803 | 093ea6a6-1077-4ea4-8a23-647e1d621b4a                                                   | 1485260588 | NULL  |
| 13163 |         1 |  178803 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab12aab5b99c                                                   | 1485260718 | NULL  |
| 13165 |         1 |  178802 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab12aab5b94c                                                   | 1485260705 | NULL  |
| 13166 |         1 |  178022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab12a4b5b94c                                                   | 1485260645 | NULL  |
| 13168 |         1 |  178022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab32a4b5b94c                                                   | 1485250645 | NULL  |
| 13169 |         1 |  178022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab32a4b5b945                                                   | 1475250645 | NULL  |
| 13170 |         1 |  176022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab32a4b5b9e5                                                   | 1465250645 | NULL  |
| 13171 |         1 |  170022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab32a4a5b9e5                                                   | 1425250645 | NULL  |
| 13172 |         1 |  170022 | 6f34579b-4745-4ec3-babd-ab32a4aeb9e5                                                   | 1426250645 | NULL  |
| 13173 |         1 |  178804 | ea7bcd3b-0f04-4ace-ba9b-a26d297029f7                                                   | 1486474710 | NULL  |
| 13174 |         1 |  178804 | 39855021-ceb8-4178-a3cc-0ba11cf4490a                                                   | 1486475039 | NULL  |
| 13175 |         1 |       2 | 6f34569b-4745-4ec3-b3bd-ab32a4aeb9e5                                                   |       NULL | NULL  |
| 13176 |         1 |       2 | 39855021-ceb8-4578-a3cc-0ba11cf4490a                                                   |       NULL | NULL  |
| 13177 |         1 |       2 | 39852021-ceb8-4578-a3cc-0ba11cf4490a                                                   |       NULL | NULL  |
| 13178 |         1 |       2 | 39855421-ceb8-4578-a3cc-0ba11cf4490a                                                   |       NULL | NULL  |
```

I'm using the `SELECT * FROM AccessToken;` query. How can I get back the result in JSON format? I wanted to do it on the database level, because when I have a big amount of data the programming level is too slow. I mean when I have 200k user to convert them to JSON using Go spent 8 seconds.

For example result:

```
{
  [
    {
      "id": 1123,
      "token": "asdjkasldkjlasdjf"
    },
    {
      "id": 11323,
      "token": "asdjkasdasdasldkjlasdjf"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What structure would you want your JSON to have?

Comment: @StefanoZanini what do you mean structure? It doesn't matter for me just getting back a normal json, but I updated for example how I want to see my data.

Comment: @LelioFaieta json_encode with what?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I didn't specified any language and: _"I wanted to do it on the database level, because when I have a big amount of data the programming level is too slow. I mean when I have 200k user to convert them to JSON using Go spent 8 seconds."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON in your example is not valid, but this should do what you desire

```
select  concat('[',
               group_concat(concat('{"id": "',
                                   col1,
                                   '", "token": "',
                                   col2,
                                   '"}'
                            ) separator ','),
               ']')
from    myTable
```

or, if you want to get an object instead of an array

```
select  concat('{ "array": [',
               group_concat(concat('{"id": "',
                                   col1,
                                   '", "token": "',
                                   col2,
                                   '"}'
                            ) separator ','),
               ']}')
from    myTable
```

The things you concatenate in the inner `concat` function will obviously depend on your table's column names.

Comment: Yes, but I thought there is a built-in function like in Postgres SELECT `array_to_json(array_agg(t)) FROM t` because in my case it was just an example and there is a go query builder where there is always different kind of queries. So it's not predictable how a query will look like.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no built-in function in MySQL that can do that